# Mongodb compound query on range number is slow

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I wish to query a mongodb collection over two values:

- restaurantId (String)
- creationTime (NumberLong epoch time)

I wish to provide a range of values for the creationTime parameter to query:

```
{"$and":[
    {"creationTime":{"$gt":"TIME_START"}},
    {"creationTime":{"$lt":"TIME_END"}},
    {"restaurantId":"ID_STRING"},
]}
```

This collection has two indexes:

```
{
    "restaurantId" : 1,
    "creationTime" : 1
}

{
    "creationTime" : 1
}
```

db.Meal.stats()

```
{
    "ns" : "waiterio_database.Meal",
    "count" : 472855,
    "size" : 1022141200,
    "avgObjSize" : 2161.637711349145,
    "storageSize" : 1180352512,
    "numExtents" : 16,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 316321792,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.1150000000386548,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 102567920,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "id" : 30586416,
        "restaurantId_1_creationTime_1" : 49939008,
        "creationTime_1" : 22042496
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

compound query explain()

```
{ 
   "cursor":"BtreeCursor restaurantId_1_creationTime_1",
   "isMultiKey":false,
   "n":100,
   "nscannedObjects":100,
   "nscanned":100,
   "nscannedObjectsAllPlans":100,
   "nscannedAllPlans":100,
   "scanAndOrder":false,
   "indexOnly":false,
   "nYields":0,
   "nChunkSkips":0,
   "millis":0,
   "indexBounds":{  
      "restaurantId":[  
         [  
            "51af5b90e4b03c3d231ee0c5",
            "51af5b90e4b03c3d231ee0c5"
         ]
      ],
      "creationTime":[  
         [  
            1435708800000,
            1.7976931348623157E308
         ]
      ]
   },
   "allPlans":[  
      {  
         "cursor":"BtreeCursor restaurantId_1_creationTime_1",
         "n":100,
         "nscannedObjects":100,
         "nscanned":100,
         "indexBounds":{  
            "restaurantId":[  
               [  
                  "51af5b90e4b03c3d231ee0c5",
                  "51af5b90e4b03c3d231ee0c5"
               ]
            ],
            "creationTime":[  
               [  
                  1435708800000,
                  1.7976931348623157E308
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "oldPlan":{  
      "cursor":"BtreeCursor restaurantId_1_creationTime_1",
      "indexBounds":{  
         "restaurantId":[  
            [  
               "51af5b90e4b03c3d231ee0c5",
               "51af5b90e4b03c3d231ee0c5"
            ]
         ],
         "creationTime":[  
            [  
               1435708800000,
               1.7976931348623157E308
            ]
         ]
      }
   },
   "server":"SERVER_HOST"
}
```

The database is hosted on Mongolab which reported that average queries takes longer that 100ms and it recommends an index (even though I already set those two).
Mongolab dashboard suggests: *unsupported query pattern*

Any idea how to set the index for the collection that would work with such a query?

(mongod version: 2.4.10)

Comment: Your indexes look ok to me. Can you post a `db.your_collection.stats()` and a `db.your_collection.find(query).explain()` for a query in question.

Comment: Your query is unnecessarily complex. Try simplifying it to: `{creationTime: {$gt: timeStart, $lt: timeEnd}, restaurantId: id}`

Comment: I added the stats() and explain() to the question @Matt.

Comment: I simplified the query as you suggested @JohnnyHK. Let's see if anything changes.